# Why doing Object.create(null) and later setting its prototype to Object.prototype will not allow to execute methods in Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was tweaking with `Object.create()` method. When I execute following code, I expect that my object should be able to use methods in `Object.prototype` but it is not doing so. Why is it so and how to overcome that?

```js
const obj1 = Object.create(null);
obj1.__proto__ = Object.prototype;

// Expectation: "[object Object]"
console.log(obj1.toString());     // Uncaught TypeError: obj1.toString is not a function
```

Also, one thing I noticed in Chrome DevTools that usually `__proto__` is in light magenta color (with opacity) while above example has `__proto__` in dark magenta color (with opacity) like it is `obj1`'s native property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__proto__` is [a setter on `Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, '__proto__'));
```

To set a prototype reliably, use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) instead.

```js
const obj1 = Object.create(null);
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj1, Object.prototype);
console.log(String(obj1));

const obj2 = Object.create(null);
console.log(String(obj2));
```